# idea,how to show "introduce local variable"?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: the picture]

This year, I started using the IDEA,that is a good tool for java,but some features I don't know how to use, how to achieve the effect, like this picture,thanks

Comment: Your screenshot is cropped so that it's hard to see what exactly happens, but most likely you need to press Alt-Enter to invoke the quickfix menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Alt + Enter` (`Cmd + Enter` on OSX) to show intention actions and then invoke "Introduce local variable". If you use a different keymap or have changed your keymap, search for "Show intention actions".

If your intention actions don't include "Introduce local variable", enable it in `Settings > Intentions >  Java > Refactorings > Introduce local variable`.